# Why expo hot reload sometimes happend with no aparent reason?

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, expo

Sometimes with no aparent reason the app gets refreshed, sometimes when i open a file. And when i add a library the expo development server crash, i think that maybe is something with watchman configuration that i don't know how to change. This is enoying.Any help?

PD: I'm using vscode

Answer (score 1):

fast refresh will happen any time a file is changed in your project directory. if you have some other tools that run in that same directory and cause files to be changed then it could be happening seemingly randomly

Comment: i know, i've disabled all the extension in vscode, and even so sometimes when i launch the app it reloads continuosly, the porcent download indicator in the bottom right becomes crazy, like there are multiple downloads at the same time, of the same thing, i'm using the expo default typescript/blank template

Comment: if you have watchman installed you can run `watchman-wait . -m 0 -p "*"` to see what files are changing in your directory